# change event of dropdown unable to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown. On its select, the change event is fired. I again select the same element from the dropdown, it does not bind the change event to it.

[image: Language Selector]

Comment: That is correct. in that case there is no change in the values so event is not fired.

Comment: what event is occurred then? any alternate answer to this @Jai

Comment: Please clarify what you wish should happen the second time you click the same selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is with `click()` event like the following:

```js
var prevVal = "";
$('#mySelect').click(function(){
  if($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0){
    var currVal = $(this).val();
    if(prevVal != currVal){
        console.log(currVal);
        prevVal = currVal;
    }
    else prevVal = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="select">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="English">English</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once option is selected from drop down, change event is not triggered on same option as there is no change with the selected value.
You can use click or focusout event, as per use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your attached image is describing a language switch. At first select, the system will change content to Spanish.

At the second click for spanish nothing will happen since the Spanish is already selected at the first click. - The details of what happens in the logic of your solution is unknown to us.